# How to swap the window.rootViewController without using an UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In the `AppDelegate` I set an `UIViewController`, let's call it **VC**, as the `rootViewControlloer` for my app:

```
-(BOOL) application: (UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  UIViewController *VC = [UIViewController alloc] init];
  self.window.rootViewController = vc;

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Once **VC** is on the screen, it asks the user a couple of questions to better configure the app before the real use.

As soon as I know what the user wants I need to swap **VC** with an `UITabBarController`, let's call it **TBC**, with three UINavigationController anchored to it.

How can I push TBC from VC **whithout** putting VC inside an `UINavigationController` and then use it to push TBC?

I am already able to accomplish the swap using the `UINavigationController`.I want a direct transiction from VC to TBC, a swap of the s`elf.window.rootViewController` whitout the need to use the extra `UINavigationController`.

Comment: What kind of visual effect? Animation or immediate? Did you try your suggestion of swapping the root VC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of navigating through the view controllers just create a method in app delegate which would change the root controller such as

```
-(void)showTBC

{
     self.TBC=[[UITabbarcontroller alloc]init];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.TBC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

and den in your VC right after the user selects the answer make an instance of app delegate
in VC such as

```
AppDelegate *ap=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and call
[ap showTBC];

…it worked for me..give it a try...